# Enviar parámetros json java

Tags: java, json, arraylist, jsonobject

tengo un inconveniente con un json. ¿Cuál seria el problema? Pues que debo enviarle parámetros. Les muestro la estructura de mi json:

```
{
   "CallContext":null,
   "LedgerJournal":{
      "Company":"prueba", 
      "JournalNameId":"D_AP",
      "parmPosted":false,
      "_LedgerJournalTrans":[
         {
            "TransDate":"2022-08-23",
            "CustAccount":"CLI-000139424",
            "InvoiceId":"001-001-0000181", 
            "AmountCurCredit":"275000",
            "PaymMode":"PRUEBA",
            "BankAccountId":"PRUEBA",
            "Txt":"PRUEBA DEPOSITO",
            "PaymReference":"BOLETA 12345",
            "DocumentNum":"12345",
            "DocumentDate":"2022-08-24",
            "BankTransType":"DEP"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Lo que hice fue crear las clases donde estarán los getters y setters. Ahora bien, pude enviar parámetros hasta **parmPosted** que estaria en la linea nro 6. Lo que quiero saber es como puedo mandar los parametros restantes a **_LedgerJournalTrans**.
Les muestro mi codigo hasta donde pude enviar los parametros:

```
PagoRequest pagoRq= new PagoRequest(); //instancio primero mi clase PagoRequest

pagoRq.setCallContext(null);//envio del primer parametro

pagoRq.setLedgerJournal(new LedgerJournal("prueba", "D_AP", false, _LedgerJournalTrans));
```

Espero que haya explicado de la mejor manera mi problema y cualquier opinion o ayuda, agradeceria muchisimo.
Gracias.

Para mayor informacion

Comment: _LedgerJournalTrans es un array con un objeto con crear una clase y ponerle propiedades; crear los setter y getter de dicha clase y luego clavarla dentro del array de _LedgerJournalTrans deberia bastar...

Comment: algo asi es a lo que me refiero: `new LedgerJournal("prueba", "D_AP", false, _LedgerJournalTrans[new LedgerJournalTrans])`

Comment: Creo que estás mirando el problema al revés. Un Json es una manera de serializar un objeto, el concepto de "enviar parámetros a un Json" no tiene mucho sentido. Lo que quieres hacer es crear un objeto que tiene una representación Json, y es al nivel de ese objeto que quieres recoger todos los parámetros antes de construirlo (a lo mejor utilizando un Builder). Luego, una vez que el objeto está completo, entonces puedes serializarlo en Json sin necesidad de especificar que los parámetros sean completos o no (si no lo fueran, el objeto java no podría estar construido)